# Unet Non-Player non-server Health syncing

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I have enemy objects spawned by the server. When they get hit, a function on them gets called to apply damage. I can't move or rename this function as it is part of a Unity asset package that has lots of interconnected parts. I can't apply damage from the attacker either for the same reason.

What I have now is that I grab the local player, use them to send a message to the server ([Command]) and the server applies the damage to the enemy on all clients.

This seems like a bad way to do this. Is there a way other than [Command] to send a message to the server to execute a function?

Note: I can't call the [Command] directly from the enemy as its not a player Authority object. Here is the relevant code:

Enemy:

```
[ClientRpc]
public void RpcTakeDamage(vDamage damage)
{
    base.TakeDamage(damage);
}

override public void TakeDamage(vDamage damage)
{
    if (!isServer)
    {
        vThirdPersonController.instance.GetComponent<NetworkLocalPlayer>().CmdTakeDamage(damage, gameObject.name);
        return;
    }
    RpcTakeDamage(damage);
}
```

On the player object:

```
[Command]
public void CmdTakeDamage(vDamage damage, string ai)
{
    GameObject.Find(ai).GetComponent<v_AIController>().TakeDamage(damage);
}

public void damageNetworkEnemy(vDamage damage, GameObject ai)
{
    CmdTakeDamage(damage, ai.name);
}
```

My question: Is there a better way to do this without finding and going through the player object? A way to message the server without using [Command]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands are the only way for a client to communicate with the server.
You could, however, pass the networkinstanceid of that enemy, which would be a much better way of referencing an object. Gameobject.find is very Slow and should alway be avoided. Another improvement would be to give the enemy a reference to his local player after spawn so he doesn’t have to look for him every time he gets hit.
Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Nice, how would I go about getting the networkinstanceid of the enemy, and then using that to find the enemy on the server?

Comment: Looking back at my code, the vThirdPersonController.instance is a network singleton that has the local network player stored. So that's already in there, but obfuscated.

Comment: I found it. You just use 'netID' on the NetworkBehaviour object. Works great!

Comment: Note that you have to use NetworkServer.FindLocalObject() or ClientScene.FindLocalObject() depending on whether you execute on the server or client.